# How do you pull an encrypted e-mail address that is attached on an url?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I am trying to pull out an encrypted email I attached to the end of a url.

I want to get the encrypted email, decrypt it and look for the record which has the same email and pull an id from that table and insert it into another table.

```
    $password = "hogehoge";
    $gethex = hex2bin($hex);
    $decrypt = openssl_decrypt($gethex, 'aes-256-ecb', $password);
    $user = $this->userinfo->getUserEmail($decrypt);
```

Comment: What is your problem in this code

Comment: Get the value from the URL using $_GET or $_REQUEST. Then reverse the process in your code that encrypts it.

Comment: I dont know what to write in order to get the encrypted email from the url.  I found something like $url = url(); but it didnt work...

Comment: Is there a laravel version to do $_GET or $_REQUEST?

Comment: What does the url structure look like? You can use `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` in laravel those are global arrays for any php script.

Answer (score 1):

Get all request parameters in laravel.

```
use Input;

$params = Input::all();
```

Comment: I couldn't get the encrypted URI. I also tried $segment = Request::segment(2); Are there any other ways to retrieve the encyrpted email that is attached to the end of the url?

Comment: By this you get all request variables including get and post